# Vulkan: SYNC-HAZARD-READ_AFTER_WRITE despite wait semaphores

Tags: graphics, rendering, vulkan

In my Vulkan application, I use "VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_ENABLE_SYNCHRONIZATION_VALIDATION_EXT" and I've got this error: "

> Validation Error: [ SYNC-HAZARD-READ_AFTER_WRITE ] Object 0: handle =
> 0xda06f70000000a0d, name = [RENDER_PASS] bloom - up sample 2, type =
> VK_OBJECT_TYPE_RENDER_PASS; | MessageID = 0x4cb75b2d |
> vkCmdBeginRenderPass: Hazard READ_AFTER_WRITE vs. layout transition in
> subpass 0 for attachment 0 aspect color during load with loadOp"

This error occurs at vkCmdBeginRenderPass execution and I understand that my render pass will try to read a framebuffer/image which is maybe not yet fully written by a previous render pass. Right ?

However, I don't understand why the validation layer detect a synchronization problem already at "vkCmdBeginRenderPass" execution. Indeed, in my application I ensure that previous render pass is completed thanks to a wait semaphore I provide in vkQueueSubmit (VkSubmitInfo.pWaitSemaphores). Of course, this vkQueueSubmit is executed after the vkCmdBeginRenderPass execution.

So, why the validation layer returns a synchronization error instead of wait the vkQueueSubmit execution to see if a wait semaphore exists ?

Comment: "*name = [RENDER_PASS] bloom - up sample 2*" The use of the name "bloom" strongly suggests that you are incorrect about the nature of your synchronization. Maybe you're not using the images you think you're using. You'll have to post an [mcve] if you want us to do more than just guess at what's wrong.

Comment: My main question is not how to fix my problem but how the validation layer can detect a synchronization problem already at "vkCmdBeginRenderPass" stage while a semaphore could exist later at "vkQueueSubmit" stage. I'm also afraid that a minimal reproducible example will be too big due to Vulkan verbosity.

Comment: "*how the validation layer can detect a synchronization problem already at "vkCmdBeginRenderPass" stage*" If the synchronization is based on something already in the command buffer, it's easy. Are you rendering to this image in a previous renderpass in the CB? Because submit semaphores only affect batches in a submission, not what happens *within* a batch.

Comment: @Saelhenen If I got a penny everytime I hear that excuse. It doesn't matter if it is big, as long as the example is minimal. As said above, error during recording largely implies problem contained within single command buffer. You could start by showing that ( ideally also in a minimal form necessary to demostrate the problem).